# excel vba autofilter not filtering on dates

Tags: excel, vba

I have column of dates, which is an output from a database. There is a macro that filters on this date which is meant to show all dates older than 14 days from current date excluding nulls. The filter when applied filters the entire sheet and shows nothing. When I take off the - 14 I do get dates, I have tried even using alt a, e, f to ensure that the column is the correct format, but no luck.

Here is my code snippet:

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=34, Criteria:="<>NULL", _
Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<" & Now()-14
```

I have tried changing the `criteria2` to `"<" & Date - 14 & "# 00:00:00 AM#"`

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Change `Criteria:="<>NULL"` to `Criteria1:="<>NULL"`

**FOLLOWUP**

The code was not working as the headings were in not in Row 1. Once the exact range was specified, it started working.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim lRow As Long

    lRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$BV$" & lRow).AutoFilter Field:=34, Criteria1:="<>NULL" _
    , Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<" & Format(Date - 14, "0")
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo error on my part as I was typing it was another screen, but that is not the error

Comment: In that case check the format of the date values in the Excel sheet. Hope they are not stored as text? I have tested your above code and it works.

Comment: If it still doesn't help then can I see a sample as well if possible

Comment: What is the best to check this, because all I know it is from an Oracle database in the following format = dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM and what is the best way to solve this

Comment: How do you want me to give the sample date? All the date is 06/04/2011 07:17

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11528/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-andy5)